Allowing widget owners to update their packages on our repository
My team maintains a repository in GitLab in which we consume other 'widgets' made in our company. Every time one of these widgets makes a change, we need to approve, merge and deploy their one line package.json package version update, which can become tedious and time consuming.
We don't really want to give everyone approve & merge permissions on our repository but is there a way to automate this process? If widget owners could update their packages on our repo with little or no help it would be a huge help to us.
Tried searching the web but couldn't find anything applicable.
